# Vue component lazy load SVG

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

im trying to lazy load an SVG when my component loads, however when running `npm run watch` and the component attempts to build it is trying to find this file, of course when the component is compiled down the path it is lazy loading will be different, so i'm getting an error at the moment stating it's unable to locate the file.

My component will compile down to `public_html/assets/js/chunks/[hash].js`, and my SVG will be within `public_html/assets/icons/manufacturer.svg`.

How can I stop it trying to compile the path and only load it on load?

```js
// component

    computed: {
        icon() {
            const icons = {
                manufacturer: () => import('../../icons/manufacturer.svg')
            }
            return icons['manufacturer'];
        },
```

Comment: If you lazy load with the [native JavaScript, 8 lines of code, ``<load-file>``  Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) there is no need for Vue at all.

Comment: Don't really want to add in additional code like that

Comment: Although it does work rather nice... :/